# cannot remount /dev/loop7 read-write,is write-protected

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mount

I'm new in this community. I would like to copy one file from one source to other source but I can't do it. Then I copy it to this directory `/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/ directory`. When I wanted it to copy it `/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/165`.

> mv: inter-device move failed: JetbrainsCrack-4.2.jar to
>   165/JetbrainsCrack-4.2.jar;  unable to remove target: Read-only file
>   system`

Then I searched from internet everyone suggested to me mount like read write then I run following script to make it read and write.

```
mount -o remount,rw /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate-165
```

Error

> mount: /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/165: cannot remount /dev/loop7
>   read-write, is write-protected

How I can make this folder to make read and write in order to copy Jetbrains.jar file into 165 folder